# Why are Bevy's Trait bounds not satisfied for the Rapier physics plugin?

Tags: rust, bevy, rapier, rapier-2d

I've been trying to run this minimal example to get [Rapier](https://rapier.rs/)'s physics working with [Bevy](https://bevyengine.org/):

```
use bevy::prelude::*;
use bevy_rapier2d::prelude::*;


fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_plugin(RapierPhysicsPlugin::<NoUserData>::pixels_per_meter(100.0))
        .run();
}
```

and it's failing:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `bevy_rapier2d::plugin::RapierPhysicsPlugin: Plugin` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:8:21
    |
8   |         .add_plugin(RapierPhysicsPlugin::<NoUserData>::pixels_per_meter(100.0))
    |          ---------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Plugin` is not implemented for `bevy_rapier2d::plugin::RapierPhysicsPlugin`
    |          |
    |          required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the following other types implement trait `Plugin`:
              AnimationPlugin
              AssetCountDiagnosticsPlugin<T>
              AssetPlugin
              AudioPlugin
              BloomPlugin
              CameraPlugin
              CameraProjectionPlugin<T>
              ColorMaterialPlugin
            and 44 others
note: required by a bound in `bevy::prelude::App::add_plugin`
   --> /home/techperson/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/bevy_app-0.9.0/src/app.rs:837:12
    |
837 |         T: Plugin,
    |            ^^^^^^ required by this bound in `bevy::prelude::App::add_plugin`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

Expected behavior is what is described in the [Rapier documentation](https://rapier.rs/docs/user_guides/bevy_plugin/getting_started_bevy).

Some info:

```
$ cargo version
cargo 1.66.0-beta.1 (7e484fc1a 2022-10-27)

$ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/techperson/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
beta-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

beta-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.66.0-beta.1 (e080cc5a6 2022-11-01)
```

Relevant part of `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
bevy = "0.9.0"
bevy_rapier2d = "0.18.0"
```

I tried manually implementing the `Plugin` trait, but can't because its from a different crate:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined outside of the crate
 --> src/main.rs:4:1
  |
4 | impl Plugin for RapierPhysicsPlugin {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------------
  | |               |
  | |               `bevy_rapier2d::plugin::RapierPhysicsPlugin` is not defined in the current crate
  | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
  |
  = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0117`.
```

I've also tried the `stable`, `beta`, and `nightly` toolchains. `beta` and `nightly` fail with the aforementioned error, and `stable` fails because `if-let` statements aren't stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bevy `0.9` is an [extremely recent release](https://bevyengine.org/news/bevy-0-9/), 3 days ago at the time of writing. It changed quite a lot about bevy internals, especially the trait system, as can be expected of an unstable project at this stage.

Most of the ecosystem will be upgrading over the course of the next few weeks. Revert back to bevy `0.8` and you should be fine for now.

Comment: This worked! Just unfortunate timing I suppose-- as of the time of writing, the tutorial (https://rapier.rs/docs/user_guides/bevy_plugin/getting_started_bevy#cargo-example) recommends using the "latest available" versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have not really tested it, only recompiled code adding the plugin and directly causing the above error. But at very least this (temporary solution) prevents that error from occurring (need to look at it bit more, but I have ran out of time for today): https://github.com/mariasiuvlad/bevy-game/pull/5/files#diff-2e9d962a08321605940b5a657135052fbcef87b5e360662bb527c96d9a615542R12

TL;DR:

```
bevy_rapier2d = { git = "https://github.com/devil-ira/bevy_rapier", branch = "bevy-0.9" }
```

EDIT: Rapier seems to have caught up with 0.9 now, so this is now inconsequential.